# Open weather api when using metrics in link getting error

Tags: javascript, json, api, ecmascript-6, openweathermap

```
fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/weather?q=${SendForm.cityName}&units=metric&APPID=******************`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(results => {
            console.log(results);
        });
```

When I don't have this part in url it pulls object normally

```
units=metric
```

But with it I get

```
Object 
    cod: "0"
    message: "Error"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a mistake in your API call:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/weather?q=London,uk&units=metric&APPID=***
```

which gives anyway:

```
{"cod":"400","message":"strconv.ParseInt: parsing \"weather\": invalid syntax"}
```

Because `forecast/weather` should be either `forecast` or `weather`.

The correct API call as documented on OWM docs, if you want to retrieve the [current weather](http://www.openweathermap.org/current):

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name},{country code}
```

or a [5 day / 3 hour forecast data](http://www.openweathermap.org/forecast5):

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city name},{country code}
```

Fixed that, the `&units=metric` seems to work correctly.